# Why can't I access global-scope variables from one file in another file?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-scope

Say I have the following code in my HTML body:

```
<script src = "first.js"></script>
<script src = "second.js"></script>
```

So in first.js I have two variables declared in a global scope. Why can't I access them from second.js?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works as expected.  Without being able to see all your relevant code it's impossible to diagnose your issue.  That's why you're being downvoted.

> index.html

```html
<script src="first.js"></script>
<script src="second.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log(firstGlobal, secondGlobal); // true true
</script>
```

> first.js

```js
var firstGlobal = true;
```

> second.js

```js
var secondGlobal = true;
```